# Pandas combine Hour and Minute column to time

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine Hour column and Minute column into HH:MM format

I tried the following

```
time = pd.to_timedelta(df['HOUR'],unit='h') + pd.to_timedelta(df['MINUTE'],unit ='m') 
time = pd.to_datetime(report_time).dt.time
```

This is working, however it shows

```
FutureWarning: Passing timedelta64-dtype data is deprecated, will raise a TypeError in a future version   return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

and it's not efficient, since I tried the code for a large dataset, and it drained my memory.

I'm wondering if there's another method to convert Hour column and Minute column into HH:MM format

My data is like

```
Hour   Minute 
 8       12
 9       30
 3       15
```

And my target is like

```
08:12
09:30
03:15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert both columns to strings, add separator and use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format` parameter:

```
time = (pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'].astype(str) + ':' + df['Minute'].astype(str), format='%H:%M')
          .dt.time)
print (time)
0    08:12:00
1    09:30:00
2    03:15:00
dtype: object
```

Another idea is multiple `Hour` by 100, add `minute`s and convert also with `%H%M` format:

```
time = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']*100 + df['Minute'], format='%H%M').dt.time
print (time)
0    08:12:00
1    09:30:00
2    03:15:00
dtype: object
```

Comment: Tried both options - the first worked for me, but the second did not - it raised the following error `ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%H%M' (match)`